# Swapping BindingList<SomeClass> elements takes a lot of time, why is that and what should I do?

Tags: c#, list, variable-assignment

I'm writing small C# application mainly for fun, and there is a DataGridView to show some data, it is bound to the BindingList. Fun started from the moment I decided to make the table sortable, that's the reason for using BindingList. As far as I understand, there's no standard implementation of this in the BindingList, but msdn has the article covering this ([about implementing sort and find for BindingList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480736.aspx)). Long story short, few lines in their implementation that cause troubles:

```
SomeClass tmp;
for(...)
{
    tmp = this[i]; //fast
    this[i] = this[position]; //slow
    this[position] = tmp; //slow
}
```

As comments show, the first assignment doesn't take much time, but other two are really slow. I fail to understand the reason behind it, but because of it sorting list 50 or so elements takes about two seconds.
Well, I can use some workaround, but it seems to be a bit ugly. Besides, I really want to know what causes such behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slow down happens because the assignment will cause anything that is bound to that list to redraw (for example, the DataGridView).

You should modify your sort method to disable raising events while the list is being changed.

```
var origRaiseEvents = this.RaiseListChangedEvents;
this.RaiseListChangedEvents = false;
try
{
    // here goes your original code.
}
finally
{
    this.RaiseListChangedEvents = origRaiseEvents;
}
```

Comment: I note that the "finally" isn't really necessary if the original code does not return. (My psychic powers sense your objection: suppose there is an unhandled exception.  OK, suppose there is an unhandled exception; the program is about to crash and die for an unknown reason! Is that really a good time to start fiddling with the event handling state of other objects? You turn the lights on in the kitchen, a bomb goes off in the basement, do you really think "let's make sure we always turn off that light before the building collapses" ?)

Comment: As long as the sorting is not called from custom code that would probably be the case. What if the BindingList is used by a component that handles exceptions to display a message like "Data not available because of ..." instead of bringing down the whole application?

Comment: Ah, now there is a good use for the finally. Excellent point. In that case however the exception would be a *handled* exception. So I withdraw my earlier statement and replace it with "A finally isn't really necessary unless the original code returns, or if there is an expected exception that will be handled at a higher level."

Answer (score 1):

The main issue, if this is a `BindingList`, is that the `DataGridView` will try to update every time you set anything within your `BindingList`.  This means the two lines that you marked as slow are most likely not slow themselves, but slow because they trigger the `DataGridView` to refresh, which means it's refreshing many times over the sort operation.

You could get around this by encapsulating the `BindingList` instead of subclassing it, and not raising the events during the sort, but wait until the sort is completed, then refresh the entire list.

Comment: Well, it sounds likely, but I'm not sure that's the case. The msdn article stated that I must call 'ListChanged' event at the end of sort function so all bound controls would refresh. I think that means they will not refresh otherwise, even on assignment.

Comment: @Michael232 If you're using BindingList's setter on index, that raises the changed events.  You should be able to subscribe to the ListChanged event yourself and verify.

Comment: @Michael232 Unless you explicitly set `RaiseListChangedEvents` to false, each assignment raises that event.